# How to check if the setup is running on Windows 10 in Inno Setup 5.5.5 or older?

Tags: inno-setup

Currently `GetWindowsVersionEx` returns version 6.3 on Windows 10 because the necessary manifest for the Windows 10 compatibility is not yet included in the currently available Inno Setup 5.5.5.

Is there any way to check if the current OS is Windows 10 until the new version of Inno Setup will be released?

I've already tried to check for the file version of kernel32.dll, but there is the same problem.

Comment: Yes. There is. But I believe that the new Inno Setup version will be released soon. Before Windows 10, I think. Is that really so urgent for you ?

Comment: We need to release a new version of our software and for the setup, I need some additional logic only for windows 10. Providing an additional setup in a few weeks is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/09/10/manifest-madness.aspx), `VerifyVersionInfo` is now subject to the same manifest-based version shenanigans that previously plagued `GetVersionEx` (and the latter is now deprecated).

The only "right" answer is to wait for a new version of Inno that includes the new manifest value.  Possibly a more time-efficient answer is to use a resource hacker program to add this value to `Setup.e32` and `SetupLdr.e32` in your current version, until such time as the new version is released.

There are some hackier solutions -- one example that I've seen was to `cmd /c ver` and then parse the output -- but I'm not going to dignify that with more detail, it's not a good idea.  Stick to the above.